# Erlang MNESIA - one-way replication to aggregate data

Tags: asynchronous, erlang, replication, aggregation, mnesia

I have multiple Erlang nodes running with an MNESIA schema. Most of my tables are local. One table called "stats" stores the usage statistics for its node. Is it possible to have one-way MNESIA replication to aggregate the stats data from all the nodes into one dedicated node?

From everything I read, data replication is a full-mesh unless the data is marked local. I am trying to find a way to do many-to-one replication.

The table is a bag and the key holds the node name to avoid nodes trampling one another. The stats need not be replicated to all the other nodes otherwise that can be a flood of unnecessary data.

Thanks!